# How do I install a printer on Ubuntu Server 12?

Tags: drivers, server, printing, samba, canon

I have Ubuntu Server 12 and I've installed Samba and CUPS.  I have also downloaded and installed the drivers for my printer.  At this point, I'm unsure of how to actually go about and install and configure the printer.  The printer is a Canon ip3600, which doesn't have support per se, but there were third-party drivers which I unpacked, modified according to the instructions, and installed.  I have the printer plugged into the server via a USB.  After googling I still haven't found instructions on installing the printer itself, though I have found plenty on configuring Samba and CUPS.  How do I go about the actual installation and configuration of the printer itself?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

First, look to see if you have the necessary packages installed correctly with the service running:

```
dpkg -l cups
service cups status
```

If CUPS is not running start it.  Here is the command to install it and an offical CUPS link:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/cups.html

If you have the GUI (desktop environment) installed on your server, simply enter this into Firefox as a URL to configure it:

```
http://localhost:631
```

If not, I'd recommend accessing the printer from another computer's web browser.  By default, network access is denied, so you'll need to allow another computer by IP address.  To do this, modify the configuration file to "Listen" to the other computer's IP address:

```
vim /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

Finally, configure the printer from the other computer by using the Ubuntu Server's IP address instead of localhost, like this:

```
http://192.168.0.3:631
```

Credit: https://www.linux.com/community/forums/printers/installing-hp-printer-in-ubuntu-1104-server

Here are a couple more links if you need them:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=310450

Comment: Thanks! It all got sorted out. Next I was just wondering how I go about getting the server to share the driver for the printer with the other machines, rather than them having to download and install their own drivers.  Could you add on how to do it or a resource that explains how?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look at that. Please just mark this question as answered and start a new question. Remember to be as detailed as possible.